Determine start and end points of line from circle to rectangle
I have a square DIV that contains a circle (a 1-pixel circumference with transparent centre) and a rectangular DIV that's filled with a rectangle (a 1-pixel perimeter with transparent centre.)
I need to draw a line that goes from the centre of the circle to the centre of the rectangle but the bits of the line that would be "behind" the circle, or the rectangle, would either be invisible or not exist. That is, the line goes from the circumference of the circle to the perimeter of the rectangle. For example:

My high school geometry is struggling :-(
I can get the centre... using JavaScript offsetWidth, offsetLeft... and I don't need absolute pixel perfection (being out a pixel doesn't matter). How do I work out the start (from the circle) to the end (on the rectangle) points?

inputs, expected output, minimal code?

draw line center to center and then draw shapes on top of it

Is rectangle aligned to X and Y axis?

Is it possible to draw the line first (from center to center) and then draw circle and rectangle for line to be behind them?

The rectangle is aligned to the XY axis. Though I can draw the shapes later that they have a transparent fill means the line from the centre will be visible.
